# "Help on this function" link in Excel 365 Function Argument not working

Tags: vba, excel, office365, chm

I have this code for building user defined functions :

```
           Application.MacroOptions 
           Macro:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(i).Value, _
           Description:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(j).Value, _
           Category:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(i).Value, _
           HelpFile:="C:\Sample\Sample.chm", _
           HelpContextID:=0, _
           ArgumentDescriptions:=args
```

But when I click the "Help on this function" link on the lower left of the Function Arguments window of my UDF, a window is prompted: "No help available." instead of displaying the .chm file. This only happens in 365, but not in my Excel 2010

Am i missing something on the code?

Comment: Where does Office 365 come in?

Comment: It only happened in Excel 365. I recently upgraded to 365 from 2010 and the code is not working anymore.

Comment: I don't use Excel 365. Excel 2013 is working for me by using e.g. `HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CHM-example.chm", _`

Comment: Is the Excel file saved in the same folder on your local drive?

Comment: Yes, it is saved in the local file. So it should work by that code above?

Comment: As mentioned above I am using Excel 2013 only. So it's more a thought. I cannot test this and you should give a try. I searched Google and don't found more questions about your problem yet.

Comment: You may want to add a test button like described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556808/excel-2010-help-on-this-function-does-not-launch-hh-exe-with-mapid-parameter/27571805#27571805 (See second code window): `MsgBox "The 'Hello World' message for testing this function!.", _
        Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbMsgBoxHelpButton, _
        HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CHM-example.chm", _
        Context:=20010`

Answer (score 1):

You code `HelpFile:="C:\Sample\Sample.chm", _` calls the CHM from `C:\Sample\`. Maybe this is blocked on your `C:\`drive by Office 365 for security.

As mentioned in my comments (see SO link) follow the steps below. Please note to add your UDF by (auto start) running a SUB like:

```
Sub AddUDFToCategory()
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' insert after Description line [optional]:    Category:=2, _ => Date & Time
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' If the UDF's are in an Addin (.xla) it's better to qualify the function name
' like this:
' Macro:=ThisWorkbook.Name & "!" & "DayName"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' see also Excel help for Application.MacroOptions
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    application.MacroOptions _
        Macro:="TestMacro", _
        Description:="This function gives back the 'Hello world' message!", _
        Category:=2, _
        HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CHM-example.chm", _
        HelpContextID:=10000
    application.MacroOptions _
        Macro:="DayName", _
        Description:="A Function That Gives the Name of the Day", _
        Category:=2, _
        HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CHM-example.chm", _
        HelpContextID:=20000
End Sub
```

For a working example go to [Online Help and Visual Basic for Applications](http://www.help-info.de/en/Visual_Basic_Applications/vba.htm)
please. Search for VBA - Download and the download link [Download Visual Basic for Applications example project (EXCEL)](http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CHM_VBA_example/CHM_VBA_example.zip).

1. download the ZIP file from the link above to a temp directory, right click the saved ZIP file first, click Properties and click Unblock
2. unzip to a temp directory.
3. as a test open CHM file first by double click
4. double click CHM_VBA_example.xls
5. first have a look to security warnings ( Excel) and set to Activate
6. follow the instructions from the Excel example worksheet.

For further information read [Using the VBA Excel Example File](http://www.help-info.de/en/Visual_Basic_Applications/vba_using_example.htm) too.